# Lots of ReaderRunnable threads still running while doing sync calls

Tags: java, okhttp

Using OkHttpClient 3.6.0

I have a stream of 100k notifications for the same SSL cert and host to send to APNS. The application reads this stream, queues them and uses an executor service with 800 threads to make a sync call as follows:

`client.newCall(request).execute()`

For the past few days, I'm seeing that we are creating lots of connections (thereby lots of ReaderRunnable threads). I know this by looking at connection count and corresponding stack trace when connection count is high. I see a lot of `OkHttp api.push.apple.com` threads that are from ReaderRunnable.

```
"OkHttp api.push.apple.com" #84247 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00002b3a7c022800 nid=0xefd3 runnable [0x00002b29f5e1e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
    - locked <0x00002b34f69a7728> (a java.lang.Object)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:930)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
    - locked <0x00002b34f69a7f48> (a sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream)
    at okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:138)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:236)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.request(RealBufferedSource.java:66)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.require(RealBufferedSource.java:59)
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Reader.nextFrame(Http2Reader.java:95)
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Connection$ReaderRunnable.execute(Http2Connection.java:566)
    at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)



2018-03-20 19:58:02 - OkHttpClient Connection Pool Count is 336
2018-03-20 19:59:02 - OkHttpClient Connection Pool Count is 12182
2018-03-20 20:00:07 - OkHttpClient Connection Pool Count is 17081
2018-03-20 20:01:02 - OkHttpClient Connection Pool Count is 19700
2018-03-20 20:02:01 - OkHttpClient Connection Pool Count is 10
```

This leads to a scenario where we sometimes hit the thread limit for a process and the application OOMs.

**Questions**

There are two questions here:

1. Why are we making so many connections? I think this is b/c APNS is returning SETTINGS_MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS = 1. Is it possible to do some frame logging to confirm? [Update: I can print the frame log but not the actual frame itself or settings.]
2. Since I'm using only 800 threads and making sync requests, even if we end up making a new connection per request, why are there more than 800 or (810 w/ idle buffer) connections in the pool at any given time?
   This is how i setup my connection timeout and connection pool when configuring the client:

   ```
   OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
   builder.connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   builder.connectionPool(new ConnectionPool(HTTP_CLIENT_MAX_CONNECTIONS, 10, TimeUnit.MINUTES));
   ```

Comment: Could you include more sample code to make it reproducible.  ideally a single file that establishes the connections and can be run by others or at least validate your statements that you only have 800 threads.  If there is a bug in your application logic, we wont know because you have just described it.

Also, please test with 3.10 in case it relates to a previously fixed bug.

Also look at using EventListener which can tell you about the connection establishment vs acquired (e.g. could have been reused).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll update to 3.10 and test again. 

On #1, do you know if there is any way to see the value of `MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS`. I can only see logging for frame logs.

Comment: I suspect only via reflection

Comment: I upgraded to 3.10. made my own custom build of okhttp client with logs to find out why connections are not reused. it ended up being that SSLSocketFactory does object equals and as a result, new connections were being created. Now i'm reusing the object and don't see the issue anymore.